# PHP RegEx capturing a bigger match ignoring a smaller match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $sentence = "{To|Preposition}{talk|Verb}{here|Place}.";

    $pattern = "/{(.*)\|(.*)}/";

    preg_match($pattern, $sentence, $match_arr);

    $match = $match_arr[0];

    $a = $match_arr[1];
    $b = $match_arr[2];

    echo "$match<br /><br />$a<br /><br />$b";
?>
```

The output is:

```
{To|Preposition}{talk|Verb}{here|Place}

To|Preposition}{talk|Verb}{here

Place
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
{To|Preposition}

To

Preposition
```

So basically, instead of capturing the first match, it just captures the entire sentence (which is technically a bigger match). How can I change the pattern to actually capture the first smaller match to get the desired result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an ungreedy match for all subgroups.

`"/{(.*)\|(.*)}/U";`

This will make the pattern match the least amount of characters possible to still satisfy the pattern. You're getting the results you're getting because the pattern `/{(.*)\|(.*)}/` is matching from the opening brace all the way to the closing one.

Comment: Ungreedy will not solve the case if the input contains {something|something|something}

Comment: @WizKid I believe that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D Worked perfectly!

Comment: Please, Please, DO NOT USE THE `U` MODIFIER - its only purpose is to _confuse_. When you need a lazy/ungreedy/reluctant quantifier, simply append a: `?`, e.g. `.*?` (as in @hwnd's answer). Besides, for this application, it would be better to use a more precise expression: `'/\{([^{}|]*)\|([^{}]*)\}/'`, which is faster, more accurate, and does not need the dot at all. (In fact, I'm very tempted to down vote this answer - for encouraging the use of the `U`.)

Comment: I did a bit of research regarding the U modifier. While I couldn't find any good articles detailing what good practice might look like, I do see your point that `?` may be more accessible than using the U modifier. I have upvoted your comment because it encouraged me to rethink my answer and ponder what the pros/cons are between the two solutions, but I don't appreciate the hostile attitude. You seem to be very knowledgeable about RegEx (I checked your profile), so you have a lot to share - but please aim to inform and teach rather than ostracize.

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow `.*` with a `?` for a [*non-greedy*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) match.

```
$pattern = "/{(.*?)\|(.*?)}/";
```

Which will output the following.

```
{To|Preposition}

To

Preposition
```

See <kbd>[Working demo](https://eval.in/153837)</kbd>

Comment: Ungreedy will not solve the case if the input contains {something|something|something}

Comment: It will for the OP's specific need.

Answer (score 0):

Change `(.*)` to `([^|]*)` then it will match every character except |

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It makes sure that there is no | character in the last item.

Comment: You are right, indeed the literal `}` stops the second capture group, otherwise the second capture group will match: "Preposition}{talk". But in this case it's better to choose `[^|}]` for the last group.